# Asynchronous indexedDB in a class object

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have written a tiny indexedDB library but dosen't seem to work as expected. So my question is how do i fix or properly reconstruct the code bellow to work as expected with a promise. I'm out of idea.
Although the add and delete method works in terms of successfully adding and deleting item from the database but the delete method won't signal it `.then` function

```
class IDB {
  constructor(name, version) {
    this.name = name;
    this.version = version;
    this.db = null;
  }
  open(callback) {
        const req = window.indexedDB.open(this.name, this.version);
        req.onupgradeneeded = (e) => {
            let db = e.target.result;
            callback(db);
        }
        req.onsuccess = (e) => {
            this.db = e.target.result;
            this.db.onversionchange = () => {
            this.db.close();
                console.log('Tell user to reload the page');
            }
        }
        req.onerror = (e) => {
            let db = e.target.errorCode;
            return;
        }
  }
  result(req) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (req) {
                req.onsuccess = (e) => {
                    let res = e.target.result;
                    if (res) {
                        resolve(res);
                    }
                };
                req.onerror = (e) => {
                    let err = e.target.errorCode;
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    }
                };
            }
        })
  }
  add(store, Items) {
        let req; 
        let tx = this.db.transaction([store], 'readwrite').objectStore(store);
        Items.forEach(item => {
            req = tx.add(item);
        });
        return this.result(req);
  }
  get(store, key) {
        let req = this.db.transaction([store], 'readonly')
        .objectStore(store).get(key);
        return this.result(req);
  }
  cursor(store) {
        let req = this.db.transaction(store).objectStore(store)
        .openCursor();
        return this.result(req);
  }
  delete(store, key) {
        let req = this.db.transaction([store], 'readwrite')
        .objectStore(store).delete(key);
        return this.result(req);
  }
}
```

Usage

```
const employeeData = [
    { id: "00-01", name: "gopal", age: 35, email: "gopal@tutorialspoint.com" },
    { id: "00-02", name: "prasad", age: 32, email: "prasad@tutorialspoint.com" }
 ];
const idb = new IDB('mydb', 1);
idb.open((db) => {
    if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('user')) {
        db.createObjectStore('user', {keyPath: 'id'});
    }
});
idb.add('user', employeeData).then(() => alert('Items added')).catch(() => alert('failed'));
```

But I would prefer the usage with the async/await code

```
await idb.add('..', ..) // blah blah
```

Comment: I suspect the `if (res) {` has something to do with it?

Comment: Rather than re-invent the wheel I would use a wrapper lib such as dexie.js that already implements promises, is well documented and more intuitive to use than native methods. There are other similar wrapper libs also